# AWS Amplify, Amazon Lex v2 and React Native - Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: sessionId

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-lex, aws-amplify

I have difficulties integrating a Amazon Lex v2 chatbot on a React Native app using Amazon Amplify.

I installed `aws-amplify` dependencies, and on my `index.js` file added the following lines:

```
import {Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';
import {AWSLexV2Provider} from '@aws-amplify/interactions';

Amplify.addPluggable(new AWSLexV2Provider());

const interactionsConfig = {
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:………',
    region: 'east-us-1',
  },
  Interactions: {
    bots: {
      // LexV2 Bot
      MyChatbotName: {
        name: 'MyChatbotName',
        aliasId: '---',
        botId: '---',
        localeId: '---',
        region: '---',
        providerName: 'AWSLexV2Provider',
      },
    },
  },
};

Amplify.configure(interactionsConfig);
```

I can call my chatbot using Python Boto3, so all the data I put in `interactionsConfig.Interactions.bots` should be okay.

But when I try to call my chatbot on `App.tsx`, with the following code:

```
async function callChatbot() {
    let userInput = 'I would like to have informations about a disease';

    // Provide a bot name and user input
    const response = await Interactions.send('MyChatbotName', userInput);

    // Log chatbot response
    console.log(response.message);
  }

  callChatbot();
```

I got an error:

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: sessionId.
Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: sessionId.
```

I suppose this is an identification issue, but the identity pool I use is supposed to have full Lex, Amplify and Cognito access…

I changed many settings in identity pool, I even tried to add user pool but still the same error… I already installed `react-native-url-polyfill`, `react-native-get-random-values` and `uuid`  to get rid of previous errors.

Do you know what I should do? Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific library that you're using to invoke Lex, but looking at the sample documentation and your error, it would appear that you need to send in additional parameters; specificall sessionId in this case. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/interact-with-an-amazon-lex2v2-bot-with-the-aws-cli-aws-sdk-for-python-and-aws-sdk-dotnet/

Comment: That's strange because I already tried to add this field in `interactionsConfig`…

Comment: I had the same issue, my problem was that my identityPoolId in the interactionsConfig had a blank space at the end.